# Pyschools Number Sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i'm doing pyschools topic 6 question 23:

Write a function getNumbers(number) that takes in a number as argument and return a list of numbers as shown in the samples given below.

Examples

```
>>> getNumbers(10)
[100, 64, 36, 16, 4, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
>>> getNumbers(9)
[81, 49, 25, 9, 1, 1, 9, 25, 49, 81]
>>> getNumbers(8)
[64, 36, 16, 4, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64]
>>> getNumbers(0)
[0]
```

This is my code:

```
def getNumbers(num):
    x = []
    y = []
    if num % 2 == 0:
        x = [i**2 for i in range(0, num+2, 2)]
        y = [i**2 for i in range(0, num+2, 2)]
        z = sorted(x, reverse=True) + y
        if z.count(0) > 1:
            z.remove(0)
            return z
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        x = [i**2 for i in range(1, num+2, 2)]
        y = [i**2 for i in range(1, num+2, 2)]
        return sorted(x, reverse=True) + y
    elif num == 1:
        x.append(num)
        y.append(num)
        return sorted(x, reverse=True) + y
```

Which works but, i'm not passing Private Test Case. Any ideea why?
Private Test Case is something made by them to see if you hard code.

```
Test Cases       Expected Result                            Returned Result
getNumbers(10)  [100, 64, 36, 16, 4, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64, 100] [100, 64, 36, 16, 4, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64, 100] 
getNumbers(9)   [81, 49, 25, 9, 1, 1, 9, 25, 49, 81]        [81, 49, 25, 9, 1, 1, 9, 25, 49, 81]    
Private Test Cases  Passed                                  Failed  
getNumbers(0)   [0]                                         [0] 
getNumbers(1)   [1, 1]                                      [1, 1]
```

Comment: What is a private test case?

Comment: from what i red somewhere, it might be something to see if the programmer is hard coding, but i don't know if i hard coded.

Comment: Try to understand that test case, then only someone can help you here based on that!

Comment: That's what it does, it seems my code is hardcoded, is there another way of achieving what i did easyer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the easiest thing to do:

```
def getNumbers(num):
    x = -num
    y = list(range(x, num+1, 2))
    return [i**2 for i in y]

getNumbers(10)
[100, 64, 36, 16, 4, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please find below a version

```
 def getNumbers(num): 
     n=list(range(num+1))
     num1=[]
     x=num
     for i in n:
      x=num**2
      num1.append(x)
      num-=2
     return num1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNumbers(num):
    return [i * i for i in range(-num, num + 1, 2)]
```

Square of a number is always positive. You need to end the range on num + 1 to include number in the result. The range is iterable, so the list around range is spurious.